# nginx virtual host same IP for 2 domains

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

My question is quite different than thousand of similar questions out there.

I have 2 dedicated servers. The stronger one is serving **MyMainDomain.com**

My weaker server but huge hard drive is hosting **MyOtherDomain.com** and also images in sub domain of my main domain above, lets say : **sub.MyMainDomain.com**. This server has 2 IP. If both **MyOtherDomain.com** and  **sub.MyMainDomain.com** are listen on same IP, **MyOtherDomain.com** will break. Solved if listen on different IP.... But that is NOT right ! We need both of them  to work on 1 IP.

```
Nginx version: nginx/1.13.8
```

Symlink in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled :

MyOtherDomain

```
server {

    listen IP_1:443 ssl http2; 
    server_name MyOtherDomain.com; # this domain must match Common Name (CN) in the SSL certificate
    ...........   
    # pass all requests to Meteor
    location / {
          proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
```

sub_MyMainDomain

```
server {

    listen IP1:443 ssl;    # error
    listen IP2:443 ssl;    # work fine
    server_name sub.MyMainDomain.com ;

  # proxy pass to minio 
  location / {
   proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
   proxy_pass http://IP1 or IP2:9000;
}
```

Nginx.conf

```
server { # this block is useless, googling sometime does not help
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server; # not sure if you want/need it here as well. Try both ways.

    server_name _;
     return 444;
}

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

}

All domains are protected by cloudflare DNS with allocated IP :

MyMainDomain.com : IP_0

MyOtherDomain.com and sub.MyMainDomain.com share IP_1 preferable

IP_2 is needed somewhere else

Comment: Aw man, why down vote me..

Answer (score 5):

Don't listen on IP. Just listen on all addresses. For example:

```
server {

    listen 443  ssl http2;

    server_name MyOtherDomain.com
}

server {

    listen 443  ssl http2;

    server_name sub.MyOtherDomain.com
}
```

Comment: No, that won't work, [https]://MyOtherDomain.com will display the content of sub.MainDomain.com

Comment: This is correct. If you still see the wrong content, the problem lies elsewhehre.

Comment: @PhamH.An this config works for me. Have you restarted nginx after configuration change? Sometimes reload not work.

Comment: Guys, thanks for your help, I guess Cloudflare server DOES mess things up. I will upvote your answer but can not accept it.

Comment: You should have mentioned Cloudflare in the question in the first place, since that is crucial information in order to provide a good answer.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen : I did mention that all domains are protected by cloudflare. I should have emphasized  on that... if I knew that was crucial